# Import Outlook Subfolder email to Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I copied the code from Youtube and made the necessary changes to reflect what I need it to do.

It works fine in importing emails to Excel, however, it only works with the emails received in my Inbox.

I don't want to import all the emails I receive but instead, I only have to choose which ones to import. My work around was to move the emails that I want to import to another folder (Inbox subfolder called "OnBoarding").

This is where I am stuck. I couldn't make it work to import emails in the Inbox subfolder "OnBoarding"

Here is the code that I use:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim outlookapp As Outlook.Application
Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set outlookapp = Outlook.Application
Set objectNS = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
```

I tried to change the path to this:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    
Dim outlookapp As Outlook.Application
Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set outlookapp = Outlook.Application
Set objectNS = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("OnBoarding")
```

But it is not working.
Please help on what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.  Missing `.Items` from the end of that last line.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set an instance of the `Items` class to a `Folders` one. Instead, you need to get a folder instance and then retrieve a corresponding `Items` object:

```
Dim outlookapp As Outlook.Application
Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim subfolder As Outlook.Folders
Dim onBoardingFolderItems as Outlook.Items

Set objectNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set subfolder = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("OnBoarding")
Set onBoardingFolderItems = subfolder.Items
```